# Get total pages of a xhtml2pdf document in view

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

does anyone knows how to get the total pages of a document generated by xhtml2pdf. I need to store the total pages in a database. In Pypdf2 I could use pdf.getNumPages() for example...

Edited:

xhtml2pdf code:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(io.BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
```

that I return to my page with:

```
return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), 
content_type='application/pdf')
```

but pdf is an object type: <class 'xhtml2pdf.context.pisaContext'>, then I can't use pypdf direct.

One idea would be save the pdf in the disk then use pypdf to read it... but I really don't want to do this

Comment: in stackoverflow, You should provide your trial code in order to get help from others.

Comment: All I can find in the github issues are recommendations to use weasyprint. In a template you can use pdf:pagecount, but is not clear how to do it in a view using xhtml2pdf - good luck.Anything stopping you from using pypdf to get the number of pages?

Comment: I edited my question with some code, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the "save to disk" part is stopping you from using `pypdf` I have good news for you: You can use a `io.BytesIO` object instead. This way you don't need to store anything on the disk.

From https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/streaming-data.html

```py
from io import BytesIO

# Prepare example
with open("example.pdf", "rb") as fh:
    bytes_stream = BytesIO(fh.read())

# Read from bytes_stream
reader = PdfReader(bytes_stream)

# Write to bytes_stream
writer = PdfWriter()
with BytesIO() as bytes_stream:
    writer.write(bytes_stream)
```